# How can I induce Slowcake's Amanuensis to arrive?

Tags: fallen-london

I am a Person of Some Importance with Notability 0. I have finally Made enough Waves to gain a point of Notable, but Slowcake's Amanuensis hasn't appeared for 5 days, and I'm worried he won't before Time the Healer does.

Is there any way to increase the chance of the Amanuensis turning up? Note that I can't summon him directly - that needs me to already be Notable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without gaining that initial point of Notability, there is no way to induce the Amanuensis to show up. Opportunity cards simply show up or they don't, and nothing in the game will affect the probability of drawing a specific one.

That said, it is possible for you to ask a fellow player who has Notability to spare to transfer one point to you. The preferred venues for this are the Failbetter forums—[this thread](http://community.failbettergames.com/topic7524-spent-your-last-point-of-notability--never-fear.aspx?page=1) should be useful—or the Fallen London IRC.

Doing this could also allow you to push for some *more* Making Waves before Time, the Healer comes and use it to move up to Notability 2.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, it came just _after_ Time, the Healer. Fortunately, the Amanuensis had turned up by then anyway :)

Comment: I did notice the "asked 2 days ago" right after answering! Glad to know you managed anyway.